# Do I need ionCube Loader, suEXEC, and suPHP to use PHP?

Tags: php, whm

I'm using WHM to set up a web server for the first time and there are options for ionCube Loader, suEXEC, and suPHP. My understanding is that suEXEC and suPHP are for security while ionCube Loader is for certain encrypted files? I'm the only user on the server (I'm not reselling hosting service), so do I need these services?

Comment: You don't need those addons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would run PHP with either mod_php or FastCGI... not suPHP (or suExec). suPHP (and suExec) slows things down and, most importantly, doesn't work with opcode caches. You don't need ionCube... it is an old school encoder/loader/cache that is just not needed.

Comment: Some commercial packages will be ioncube encrypted, and you'd need it to run those, but if you're writing  your own scripts, you won't need it. (IonCube actually compiles the script to bytecode.)

Comment: To add to what TecBrat is saying, unless a commercial script is encoded with something (ionCube or Zend Guard or some such) you have no need for one of those products.

Comment: Encoding your own website files gives the chance for anti malware protection and real time intrusion detection if that's important for you, but if not going down that path at the moment and not needing to run scripts that are protected, you don't need the Loader so leave it off. The fewer components you install, the less there is to maintain, upgrade, accidentally break etc. Disclosure: I am associated with ionCube.